# I forked a package and now I can't get it to download to my project due to conflicts with requirments

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I forked a package laravel-theme by igaster, I did not create dev-master but decided to use master since I do not plan to fall back on the original package, but instead add new functionallity that is unique to my app, so I kept master and did a small push just to test something.

When I run composer update igaster/laravel-theme I got this message:

> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>      - The requested package igaster/laravel-theme master is satisfiable by > igaster/laravel-theme[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

This is code inside composer.json for this specific fork

```
   "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/laracraft/laravel-theme"
        }
    ],
    "require": {

        "igaster/laravel-theme": "master"
```

What am I doing wrong to not be able to complete the update successfully? Any ideas?

Update:

tried "igaster/laravel-theme": "master as 1.3", as suggested and got this:

[image]

Comment: Change `"igaster/laravel-theme": "master"` to point to `dev-master`.   `"igaster/laravel-theme": "dev-master"`

Comment: this is correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package which once `composer.json` requires a more stable version of your package than master.

```
"igaster/laravel-theme": "master as 1.3",
```

With this trick you can fake a more stable version as long as you don't want to tag it yourself accordingly. Scan the error messages to find out the proper minimum stable version and replace the `as 1.3` to what is needed in your case.

Comment: check my updated question, I tried with master as 1.3 but got same error.

Comment: Worth taking a look at: http://webtips.krajee.com/setting-composer-minimum-stability-application/ then

Comment: thank you, will do :) time to learn something new! :) btw dev-master did the trick as btl suggested above, not sure why that worked but it did...

Comment: It did because of 'stability level' requirement. When you ask it to require master, you tell composer to look for a stable release named master. But the package has no stable releases, it only has dev-master releases, which are not considered 'stable-enough' by composer.